# How to place a Progress bar over or inside an App Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, appbar

Does anyone have any idea whether or not I can include a progress bar within an app bar? See screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to reuse code and if I can create an App Bar with a Progress Indicator and then the same without. This will enable the users to complete this screen on signup and then EDIT this screen without the progress bar once they have an account. Is this even possible?

[image: Progress App Bar]

Answer (score 1):

Your best option here is to use the 'bottom' property of the appBar widget it would look something like this

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
// this is to hide the progress inidecator once the account is created
  bool isSignUpComplete = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// this is to retrieve the device screen size
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: !isSignUpComplete ? PreferredSize(
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          preferredSize: Size(size.width, 0),
        ) : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to make a progress indicator in the app bar you can use the progress indicator in the  title of the app bar but :

if you want to make it such as the image I will tell you how you can make a custom app bar below the progress indicator like this

```
class Myapplication extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              LinearProgressIndicator(),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined, color: Colors.black),
                ],
              ),
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by putting the progress bar in the body, extended the body behind the app bar and then made the app bar transparent.

```
class SignUpForm extends StatelessWidget {
  double progress = 0.22;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,

    appBar: BasicFormAppBar(),

    body: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 45),
        Container(
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: progress,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.Blue),
            backgroundColor: Colors.Grey,
          ),
        ), //column & scaffold are not closed in this snippet
```

Comment: Please share a short sample of your solution